# Detect if Raycast hit a programatically created game object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, detection

I have 4 rectangles of identical size (each in every quadrant of screen). I created them programatically in onStart() method:

```
Vector3 pos1 = new Vector3(Screen.width / 4, Screen.height / 4, 0);
Vector2 rectDimensions = new Vector2(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2);

GameObject bottomLeftGO = new GameObject();
bottomLeftGO.transform.SetParent(mainCanvas.transform);

Image bottomLeftRect = bottomLeftGO.AddComponent<Image>();
bottomLeftRect.color = new Color(0.192F, 0.051F, 0.125F);
bottomLeftRect.rectTransform.sizeDelta = rectDimensions;
bottomLeftGO.transform.position = pos1;
```

Currently, screen looks like this:
[image: RectangleScene]

mainCanvas is a prefab I created in Unity GUI, and connected it to the script in which I made rectangles.

I want to detect touches on the rectangles in Update() method. I tried using Raycast like this:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0)
{
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(touch.position);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, touchInputMask))
        {
            GameObject hittedObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

But the condition 
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
always returns false. I tried it using Input.GetMouseButton(0) so I do not need to build .apk on phone, but it still fails to detect any hits.

I am fresh new to Unity and do not understand all the concepts, so If anyone has an idea what could I try or has the solution I would be more than glad to listen. Thank you.

Comment: Change Image to Button :D. AND ................ wait for it ......... legendary ...

Comment: You really don't have to use  a `Button` here if it doesn't need `Text` and all those transition stuff. If you simply want to detect click on an image then `Image` component is fine. You don't raycast UI elements with `Physics.Raycast`. How to do this is provided in the first part of answer in the duplicated question.

Comment: @Programmer How do I attach that "ClickDetector" script to a programatically created object? Do I even have to do it or it's an event handler for all clicks/touches?

Comment: Never mind, I understood everything. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!